# Is it possible to authenticate skype ID from web application?

Tags: skype

Here is my case. If the user enters his skype ID into my website, my website will check if this ID is correct or not by allowing the user to authenticate (i.e. entering skype ID and password) via my website. 
This is just an idea, so I'd like to know if it is possible to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use Microsoft authentication, and skype can use it too.

Comment: But can be problem if MS account and Skype are't linked for particular user.

Comment: I'm still looking for the idea that user can just use his skype ID to authenticate instead of email. :( But still cannot find it.